# MySQL query to find records that don't exist with multiple duplicate values

Tags: mysql, select, join, duplicates

I have two similar tables that I need to locate any records that exist in one table but not the other, but the only value I have to find these records have multiple duplicate values.

Table 1:

`TId    Date       TYPE     AMOUNT
1     2014-02-01   23        25.34
2     2014-02-01   23        46.95
3     2014-02-01   23        46.95
4     2014-02-01   23        25.34
5     2014-02-01   23        21.01`

Table 2:

`TId    Date       TYPE     AMOUNT
7     2014-02-01   23        25.34
8     2014-02-01   23        46.95
9     2014-02-01   23        21.01`

I need to query the two tables to locate records 3 and 4 from table 1. The issue is I'm finding a match in records 7 and 8 in table 2. I've used 'NOT EXISTS' and 'JOIN' but can't seem to get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: What's the desired result? What's the condition to differentiate?

Comment: Desired result would be to return records 3 and 4 from table 1.

Comment: Ok but what's the condition/business logic to differentiate them?

Comment: Two sets of data, PO system and  bank statement. I need to find the the records that are on the bank statement but not in the PO system. The problem is most of the purchases are for the same amount. 
In the sample data I have bank statement in table 1 and pos in table 2.  
I need to locate the amounts that appear on the bank statement but are not in the PO system. I don’t care what record it is, just the amount so the customer can investigate which one was not entered into the PO system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on what you want to find, but it sounds like you want the records on table 1 that are not on table 2, based on the date, type and amount.

If so a left join and checking for NULL on a field is probably the best way to do it:-

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.Date = table2.Date
AND table1.Type = table2.Type
AND table1.Amount = table2.Amount
WHERE table2.TId IS NULL
```

Possibly like this (depending on your exact requirements). This should get all the records from table1, and join that against a record where the date, type and amount match AND the tid is the first for that record. Then joined against table2. Records put out if there is no match on table2, or there is a match but the records on table1 is not the first one that would match.

The does only work if there are no duplicates on table2.

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Date, TYPE, AMOUNT, MIN(TId) AS TId
    FROM table1 
) t11
ON table1.Date = t11.Date
AND table1.Type = t11.Type
AND table1.Amount = t11.Amount
AND table1.TId = t11.TId
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.Date = table2.Date
AND table1.Type = table2.Type
AND table1.Amount = table2.Amount
WHERE (t11.TId IS NULL
AND table2.TId IS NOT NULL)
OR table2.TId IS NULL
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it still finds a match for table1 3 & 4, in table2 7 & 8.

Comment: But those are matches. What is is you need to use to determine if something is a match or not?

Comment: I thinks that's the issue, I don't have much data to work with. I need to uniquely match the data, so record 7 matches record 1 then it shouldn't match record 4. Once it finds a match it shouldn't be used again.

Comment: Ahh, right. Makes it a bit more complex. Will have a play